# Direct Reduction, Turing machine and a DFA

Tags: logic, reduction, turing-machines, decidable

I have been reading and I am trying to understand the reduction when it comes to truing machine. This is how I understand it: it means that it reduces problem A into problem C. But I am not quite sure how it totally works.
lets see an example:

Given the language L:

```
L ={<M,D>| M is s TM and D is a DFA so that L(M) = L(D)},
```

using reduction how to prove `Atm < L.`

My solution:

M is a Turing machine that accepts any string and it halts on that string.
D is DFA hast accepts the language L and its equivalent to TM M.
Atm is a TM, M that accepts string *w*.

How can you prove using a direct reduction that `Atm < L??`

Comment: This should go in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov I have also published it there.

Answer (score 1):

We need to show that a decider for L can be used to decide instances of Atm, that is, a decider for L can be used to answer the question "does a given TM accept a given input string?"

Given an instance `<M, w>` of Atm, we need to transform it into an instance `<M', D>` of this problem so that a solution to this problem will answer the other.

First, construct `M'` so that `L(M') = L(M) intersect {w}`. This can be done as follows. Create a TM that scans the input tape and ensures that `w` is the input. If `w` is not the input, halt-reject. Otherwise, return to the front of the tape and transition to the formerly initial state of `M`. Then, run `M` as normal. Clearly, this can only possibly accept `w`, since we rejected everything else; and if `M` accepts `w`, this will as well, since after the initial phase `M` runs normally.

Second, construct `D` so that `L(D) = {w}`. This `DFA` will have `|w| + 2` states: an initial state, a dead state, and one state per symbol in `w`.

Now, use our decider for `L` on the instance `<M', D>`. It will halt-accept if and only if `L(M') = L(D) = {w}`, which is only possible if `L(M) intersect {w} = {w}` which in turn is only satisfied if `L(M)` contains `w`. So if we halt-accept, then we have an answer to our instance `<M, w>` of Atm.